# How to close all threads on Browser close event?

Tags: asp.net

I have website which runs multiple threads. When user close the browser but threads are still running. How to kill/stop all thread in asp.net on browser close.

Comment: Hi Sandy. You cannot kill server thread, and you cannot kill browser threads. The server is shared by all client. You need a serious rampup on web and asp.net server - client architecture. I suggest this link: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp to start with

Comment: I am talking about my apllication level threads not server or client thread. In my application i have created a thread now i wanna stop that at browser close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no message sent to the server when the browser closes so there's no preemptive event to listen to. What you'll want to do is make a variable available to your threads that indicates when the user last requested a resource from your server. Once a certain amount of time has passed since the user last requested expires you end the threads. Then, in your HTML add a javascript ajax request that pings your server to keep the threads alive.

Obviously you'll need to tweak the timeouts to balance performance and reliability for your users.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a KillThreads action in the server and call it with AJAX when you detect the user is attempting to close the browser in the client.